# Why does the Android SDK have packages?

Tags: java, sdk, android-sdk-2.3

I know about packages in the context of Linux distributions. But when I download for example the Java SDK (or OpenJDK), it's just the Java SDK. No packages. Why does the Android SDK have packages? What are those packages and why is it necessary to have packages? Are these the same kind of "packages" that I have on a Linux distribution or is the term "package" referring to something slightly different in the context of an SDK? I am confused because I always thought an SDK gives you what you need to build software. Like ... everything that you need. Not just a part of what you need and then later you need to find out which packages you need.

Comment: Maybe clarify what you mean by "packages", which is an overloaded term, especially given that the SDK is in Java. Maybe post a screenshot of which "packages" you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK includes sample projects with source code, development tools, an emulator, and required libraries to build Android applications. Applications are written using the Java programming language and run on Dalvik, a custom virtual machine designed for embedded use which runs on top of a Linuxkernel.